# change html anchor to markdown

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code to iterate all the files in a directory:

```
fs.readdir(root, (err, folders) => {
  folders.forEach(folder => {
    const current = path.join(root, folder)
    fs.readdir(current, (err, files) => {
      if (err) {
        return
      }

      files.filter(f => path.extname(f) === '.md').forEach(f => {
        const file = path.join(current, f)
        console.log(file)
      })
    })
   fs.readFile(current, 'utf8', (err, text) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err)
      }

      // convert anchors to markdown

      fs.writeFile(current, text.join('\n'), 'utf8', err => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          throw err
        }
      })
    })
  })
})
```

If I have an anchor tag like this:

```
<a href="https://www.link.com/" target="_blank">link</a>
```

How can I pull all these links out of a file and convert them into markdown links like this:

```
[link](https://www.link.com/)
```

I am using node to iterate over the files in a directory.

Comment: I have following code? What code

Comment: @mplungjan oops, updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're reading from a `.html` file?

If you are, then I suspect you'll be looking for all anchor tags within the file.

```
let pattern = /<a.*?href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/g,
    matches = text.match(pattern),
    new_text = matches.map(i => i.replace(pattern, '[$2]($1)'));
```

This snippet will store all link tags in an array and convert them all to markdown. That way you can perform `new_text.join('\n')` with ease.